# Google Scripts: Sending Two Different Emails Based on 2 Different Conditions

Tags: google-apps-script

I'm trying to write a Google script to send two different emails with different subject lines based on which column has been edited. Column D (Start Date) would generate an Onboarding Email, and Column E would generate an Offboarding Email. I am able to send either one or the other (i.e. if either column changes it sends an email with one subject line. This is the code that I'm using - would love any help! Thanks - Nicole

```
function triggerOnEdit(e)
{
  showMessageOnUpdate(e);
}

function showMessageOnUpdate(e)
{
  var range = e.range;

  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert("range updated " +   range.getA1Notation());  
}

function checkEndDate(e)
{
  var range = e.range;

  if(range.getColumn() <= 5 && 
     range.getLastColumn() >=5 )
  {
    var edited_row = range.getRow();

    var status = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange(edited_row,5).getValue();
    {
      return edited_row;
    }
  }
  return 0;
}


function triggerOnEdit(e)
{
  showMessageOnUpdate(e);
}
function showMessageOnUpdate(e)
{
  var edited_row = checkEndDate(e);
  if(edited_row > 1)
  {
    SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert("Row # "+edited_row+" start date edited!");
  }
}

//COMPOSE THE END DATE EMAIL

function sendEmailOnEndDate(e)
{
  var edited_row = checkEndDate(e);

  if(edited_row <= 0)
  {
    return;
  }

  sendEmailByRow(edited_row);
}

function sendEmailByRow(row)
{
  var values = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange(row,1,row,4).getValues();
  var row_values = values[0];

  var mail = composeEndDateEmail(row_values);

  //Uncomment this line for testing
  //SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert(" subject is "+mail.subject+"\n message "+mail.message);

  MailApp.sendEmail(admin_email,mail.subject,mail.message);
}


function composeEndDateEmail(row_values)
{
  var first_name = row_values[0];

  var last_name = row_values[1];

  var email = row_values[2];

  var end_date = row_values [4];

  var message = "OFFBOARDING: "+end_date+" "+first_name+" "+last_name+
    " email "+email;
  var subject = "OFFBOARDING: "+end_date+" "+first_name+" "+last_name

  return({message:message,subject:subject});
}
//Call Compose End Date Trigger

function triggerOnEdit(e)
{
  sendEmailOnEndDate(e);
}

var admin_email='myemail@.gmail.com';

function sendTestEmail()
{
  MailApp.sendEmail(admin_email,'offboarding test email from script ',
'Offboarding test');

}
```

Comment: Why do you declare `triggerOnEdit` so many times?

Comment: I recommend that you put all of your onEdit triggered functions into the same function  so that you can manage when and in what order they should function.  At this point it's hard to tell what you want.  Perhaps you could explain it in words.  When does each function run.?

Comment: Thanks for your willingness to help! Honestly, I used the code from this blog: https://blog.gsmart.in/send-email-when-cell-value-changes-in-google-sheets/ but in retrospect I don't need all of the onEdit functions. All I need is an email to be sent with the subject "Onboarding" when Column D is edited and a different email with the subject "Offboarding" to be sent when Column E is edited.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your goal can be achieved by using an installable trigger which would be triggered by an `on edit` action.

```
function onEditInst(e) {
  var range = e.range;
  if (range.getColumn() == 4)
    MailApp.sendEmail("mail@address.com", "Onboarding Email", "Column D has been edited");
  else if (range.getColumn() == 5) 
     MailApp.sendEmail("mail@address.com", "Offboarding Email", "Column E has been edited");
}
```

The above snippet gathers the edited range in the sheet and checks whether it is the `D` or the `E` column. Afterwards based on that an email is being sent - either `Onboarding` or `Offboarding`.

To install the trigger just go to current project's triggers and add a trigger with the below options:

[image: trigger settings]

**Reference**

- [Installable triggers Apps Script](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable);
- [Range Class Apps Script - getColumn](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getcolumn).

Comment: ale13 you are my hero! That worked and that was the fix-  Thank you so much!

Comment: @NicoleWoods I am glad my solution worked for your situation! :) If you found it helpful please don’t forget to mark the answer as accepted since others might encounter the same issue and it might be of help! Cheers!